# How do I remove controller from pipeline during startup?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have several Controllers in my web application that are displayed in swagger interface.
I would like to remove some of them optionally during startup so client should get 404 error (Notfound) when he tries to access removed controller and swagger should not display removed controller as well. I would like to completely remove some controllers from pipeline. How can I do that?

Comment: Removing them from the pipeline isn't the right approach; besides,Controllers aren't actually added to the pipeline directly: instead they're invoked by the endpoint handler and controller factory. You should use a middleware or action-filter to intercept/modify/hide endpoints (like controller actions) instead. (also, since ASP.NET Core 6 [everything changed again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846127/what-are-the-differences-between-app-userouting-and-app-useendpoints))

Comment: will your approach remove controller from swagger too?

Comment: No, instead to hide controllers from Discovery/Swagger/OpenAPI you should use `[OpenApiIgnore]` (or `[SwaggerIgnore]`) on your `abstract class MyBaseMvcController : Controller` which should be the subclass of all "MVC" (not Web API) controllers in your project, that way _all_ MVC controllers will be excluded without any extra work.

Comment: ok, do I understand correctly that I should use a kind of IResourceFilter attribute (to return 404) and a kind of Swagger attribute to remove from Swagger (do they work conditionally?). I guess it would be much easier to remove controller from pipeline at startup :)

Comment: What kind of "conditional" behaviour are you after?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it in my question directly, but I would like to remove controllers conditionally using configuration. Every controller may be turned on or turned off depending on configuration during startup (thanks God not during runtime).

Comment: ...why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally have found solution (though not exactly what I wanted) here:
[How can I exclude a controller from ASP.NET Core 3 Attribute Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324768/how-can-i-exclude-a-controller-from-asp-net-core-3-attribute-routing)

Comment: BTW another possibility is to reimplement `IControllerFactory` and uses its own DI-provided configuration to pass a list of `Type` that identify the `Controller` subclasses in an allowlist or blocklist.